# Checking for port exhaustion using WireShark

Tags: windows, port, wireshark

We have been having some rare port exhaustion issues on our computers. We deployed a little netstat monitoring app that tracks the amount of TIME_WAIT statuses per application and notifies us if there are more than usual. One suggestion was that our netstat tool would not help us find the culprit application and check something else using Wireshark.

Since we are tracking port exhaustion, would it be possible to check which application is opening and closing their ports rapidly? And log that information somewhere in Wireshark?

Comment: If you're referring to the netstat command in Windows, you can display the executable and/or the PID responsible for the connection. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/netstat

Comment: My first paragraph does mention that I've already been using netstat and I can see the PID information just fine. My question was regarding the fact that if I can see the same information using Wireshark? And then if possible track how fast they're opening and closing.

Comment: Yes, I know you're using netstat. That's why I commented. I missed the part that you were getting info per application. My apologies. Carry on.